# Торговая площадка steam

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли вытянуть информацию обо всех вещах с торговой площадки steam? Желательно в json формате.

```
<?php
$customUrl = "apocalypsys";
$url = "http://steamcommunity.com/id/$customUrl/inventory/json/730/2";

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents("$url"),true);
foreach($json["rgDescriptions"] as $key => $value)
    {
        if($json["rgDescriptions"]["$key"]["tradable"] == 1 && $json["rgDescriptions"]["$key"]["marketable"] == 1)
            {
            $market_hash_name = rawurlencode($json["rgDescriptions"]["$key"]["market_hash_name"]);
            $price = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=0&appid=730&market_hash_name=$market_hash_name"),true);
            if($price["success"] == 1)
                {
                echo $json["rgDescriptions"]["$key"]["market_name"]." lowest price: ".$price["lowest_price"]." median price:".$price["median_price"]."</br>";
                }
            }
    }
?>
```

Так я пытался получить цену собственного инвентаря. На 21-ом элементе инвентаря сервер говорит:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429

p.s. Конечно хотелось бы сделать собственную копию ТП в БД и обновлять её несколько раз в сутки.

upd: Подскажите можно ли имитировать ssl соединение?

Comment: А что у них написано по поводу использования их данных?

Comment: Единственное о чём я слышал - так это только об ограничении количества запросов к ТП с одного IP.

Comment: Целевой сервер вам как бы намекает [`HTTP/1.0 429`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#429). Этот код означает "Too many requests". Используйте таймауты при обращении к API и будет вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение ошибки, но как научить file_get_contents() делать запросы раз в 2-3 секунды? Если это и  исправит ошибку - тогда время получения всего "инвентаря" будет занимать некоторое время(180 вещей * 2-3 секунды = 6-9 минут).

Comment: @Apocalypsys я также пробовал получить цены инвентаря. Задержка была 6 секунд. В итоге где-то на 100+ запросе пришла ошибка 429 и блокирование IP на 5 минут, потом на 15 и потом на сутки.

Comment: Apocalypsys, как вариант, увеличьте время исполнения скрипта на сервере и между запросами используйте ф-ю sleep().
Дабы попытаться избежать проблемы @ЕвгенийКидяев, устанавливайте рандомное время ожидания.

Comment: Виталий, даже если выставить "sleep(1)" это увеличит время загрузки страницы.

Comment: @Apocalypsys вы работаете с апи, владелец которого прямо заявляет о наличии ограничений. В чем суть вопроса? Как это ограничение обойти? (Никак, иначе бы ограничения не было)

Comment: @PashaPash Суть вопроса - как получить весь список товаров с торговой площадки?

Comment: Прокси на каждый запрос.

Answer (score 1):

Делайте запросы с разных IP адресов (если аккаунт не проверяется, тогда придется еще зарегистрировать несколько дополнительных). Например, есть VPN сервисы, в которых можно менять сервер (платите 300-500 р. в месяц). Тогда можно запускать скрипт сразу от кучи аккаунтов/ip адресов, и у Вас будет не 20 запросов в единицу времени, а 20*N.

У ряда сайтов с такими ограничениями есть бага, в которой запись о коннекте записывается после окончания обработки запроса (причина в том, что commit в базу происходит в конце обработки). Так что если вместо 20 последовательных Вы сделаете 10000 параллельных, то, возможно, все они завершатся успешно.

Answer (score 0):

ну в общем то можно , но тут придется использовать стороннее api , 
я реализовал это для steambot на nodejs следующим образом

`//парсинг цены итемов
var g_PricesUpdate = 300; // интервал в секундах
var prices;
function getprices(){
   request('https://api.csgofast.com/price/all', function(error, response, body) {
       prices = JSON.parse(body);
       if(response.statusCode != 200) {
           logger.info("Не могу загрузить цены с сайта. Юзаю Файл.");
           if(fs.existsSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt')){
               prices = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/prices.txt'));
               logger.info('Старые Цены Загружены!');
           }
       } else {
           fs.writeFileSync('prices.txt', body);
           logger.info('Цены Успешно Обновлены!');
       }
   });
}
setInterval(function(){getprices();},g_PricesUpdate*1000);
getprices();
///////////////////////////////////`

не думаю что будет сложно переписать под php , в итоге файл получаем со следующим содержимым

`{"StatTrak™ Dual Berettas | Dualing Dragons (Battle-Scarred)":0.28}`